# rdiff-backup with timestamps instead checksums

Tags: backup, rsync, rdiff-backup

I switched my personal "backup" from rsync to rdiff-backup.
rsync compares only file timestamps and rdiff-backup uses checksums on files.
So rdiff-backup needs much more time (10 minutes vs 80 minutes)

Is there a way to use rdiff-backup also only with timestamps? Or another backup alternative using timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at borgbackup.

The "did it change?" check is based on ctime, inode number and size. It is very fast if these did not change.

Comment: thx, for the hint to borgbackup, I tried it but it has other disadvatages. I really like rdiff-backus backwards deltas and always having an builed